# React adding new users to SQL database (undefined entries)

Tags: sql, node.js, reactjs, express

I have been making a website in which I am beginning to create a registration process.I have created the registration form and a server.js file using npm express. However this keeps throwing this error and I'm not sure why.

This is the error

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'email' of 'req.body' as it is undefined.

All I want to do is so that when submit button is clicked it the users are simply added to the database.

This is the server.js (The error occurs within this file from what I can gather)

```
const express = require("express");
const sql = require("mssql");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => `Server running on port ${port}`);

const config = {
  user: "sas",
  password: "Mypassword456",
  server: "DEVSQL_2014", // You can use 'localhost\\instance' to connect to named instance
  database: "TestDBWebsite"
};
app.post("/admin-Add-Users", function(req, res) {
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

  const { email, password } = req.body;
  let connection = new sql.ConnectionPool(config, function(err) {
    let request = new sql.Request(connection);
    request.query(
      "insert into Login (email, password) values ('" +
        password +
        "', '" +
        email +
        "')"
    );
  });
  res.send({ message: "Success" });
});
```

register.js

```
import React from "react";

import "../bootstrap.min.css";
import logo from "../codestone logo.png";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Popup from "reactjs-popup";

import { Formik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

function Register() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <DisplayUsersCS />
    </div>
  );
}

class DisplayUsersCS extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = { users: [] };
    this.onSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = this;
    // On submit of the form, send a POST request with the data to the server.
    fetch("/admin-Add-Users", {
      method: "POST",
      body: {
        email: self.refs.email,
        password: self.refs.password
      }
    })
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(body) {
        console.log(body);
      });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.users);
    return (
      <div>
        <LoginForm></LoginForm>

        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input type="text" placeholder="email" ref="email" />
          <input type="text" placeholder="password" ref="password" />
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const LoginForm = () => (
  <Formik
    class="form-signin"
    action="auth"
    method="POST"
    initialValues={{ email: "", password: "", passwordConfirm: "" }}
    onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Logging in", values);
        setSubmitting(false);
      }, 500);
    }}
    validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
      email: Yup.string()
        .email()
        .required("Required")
        .matches(/(?=.*codestone)/, "This is not a Codestone email address."),

      password: Yup.string()
        .required("No password provided.")
        .min(8, "Password is too short - should be 8 chars minimum.")
        .matches(/(?=.*[0-9])/, "Password must contain a number."),

      passwordConfirm: Yup.string()
        .required("No password provided.")
        .min(8, "Password is too short - should be 8 chars minimum.")
        .matches(/(?=.*[0-9])/, "Password must contain a number.")
    })}
  >
    {props => {
      const {
        values,
        touched,
        errors,
        isSubmitting,
        handleChange,
        handleBlur,
        handleSubmit
      } = props;
      return (
        <form
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
          class="form-signin"
          action="auth"
          method="POST"
        >
          <div className="jumbotron">
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <input
              name="email"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter your email"
              value={values.email}
              onChange={handleChange}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              className={errors.email && touched.email && "error"}
            />
            {errors.email && touched.email && (
              <div className="input-feedback">{errors.email}</div>
            )}

            <label htmlFor="email">Password</label>
            <input
              name="password"
              type="password"
              placeholder="Enter your password"
              value={values.password}
              onChange={handleChange}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              className={errors.password && touched.password && "error"}
            />
            {errors.password && touched.password && (
              <div className="input-feedback">{errors.password}</div>
            )}
            <label htmlFor="email">Password Confirmation</label>
            <input
              name="passwordConfirm"
              type="passwordConfirm"
              placeholder="Confirm Password"
              value={values.passwordConfirm}
              onChange={handleChange}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              className={
                errors.passwordConfirm && touched.passwordConfirm && "error"
              }
            />
            {errors.passwordConfirm && touched.passwordConfirm && (
              <div className="input-feedback">{errors.passwordConfirm}</div>
            )}

            <button type="submit" action="auth">
              Sign Up
            </button>
            <p>
              <Link to="/Login"> Login </Link>
            </p>
            <p>
              <Link to="/reset"> Reset Password </Link>
            </p>
          </div>
        </form>
      );
    }}
  </Formik>
);

function Header() {
  return (
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <img
        className="profile-image"
        alt="icon"
        src={logo}
        width="450"
        height="80"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
export default Register;
```

Answer (score 0):

#### On client side (react)

To use `fetch` to post json data, you need to stringify the data in the body

```
fetch('https://example.com/profile', {
  method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((data) => {
  console.log('Success:', data);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

#### On server side (express.js)

You need to include include middleware in order to read the request body. You can refer to the sample codes here https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Comment: Ho would I implement that into my project ?